# SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL error when updating packages from git via composer

Tags: github, composer, openssl

Когда пытаюсь обновить модули с github через composer командой `composer update` выпадает ошибка error fatal: unable to access 'https: // ***************': OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to proxy.pdsggg.com.ua:8080'

Данные полученные командой `composer diag`

Checking composer.json: WARNING
require.php-amqplib/php-amqplib : exact version constraints (2.7.0) should be avoided if the package follows semantic versioning

Checking platform settings: OK
Checking git settings: OK

Checking http connectivity to packagist: OK

Checking https connectivity to packagist: OK

Checking HTTP proxy: OK

Checking HTTP proxy support for request_fulluri: OK

Checking HTTPS proxy support for request_fulluri: OK

Checking github.com rate limit: OK

Checking disk free space: OK

Checking pubkeys:

Tags Public Key Fingerprint: 57815BA2 7E54DC31 7ECC7CC5 573090D0  87719BA6 8F3BB723 4E5D42D0 84A14642

Dev Public Key Fingerprint: 4AC45767 E5EC2265 2F0C1167 CBBB8A2B  0C708369 153E328C AD90147D AFE50952

OK

Checking composer version: You are not running the latest stable version, run composer self-update to update (1.10.7 => 2.0.9)

Composer version: 1.10.7

PHP version: 7.4.7

PHP binary path: D:\Users\fghf\php\php-7.4.7\php.exe

OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

С чем может быть связана эта ошибка?

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Comment: Вы пробовали открыть `https: // ***************` в браузере? Ошибка `SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL` означает, что не получается установить соединение. Например, сервер закрыл соединение посреди хэндшейка.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос закрыт. В переменных среды ОС был прописан неправильный прокси сервер. Его удаление убрало ошибку.